# Hibernate seems to create wrong SQL Query from HQL Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to extend my database program with a function to execute any hql query. I'm almost done with it but I get an error on the following process.

```
select p.reviews, p.title from Product p
```

This hql query is converted in an sql query as following:

```
Hibernate: select . as col_0_0_, product0_.title as col_1_0_, reviews1_.account_number as account_1_2_, reviews1_.product_id as product_2_2_, reviews1_.points as points3_2_, reviews1_.review as review4_2_ from dbprak12.view_product_meta product0_ inner join dbprak12.view_customer_evaluates reviews1_ on product0_.product_id=reviews1_.product_id
```

As you can obviously see, there will be thrown an error with sql state code 42601. Because " . as col_0_0_..." isn't correct syntax. But I don't understand why hibernate creates this sql query.

I use the following two xml mappings:

Product.hbm.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="media.definitions.Product" table="dbprak12.view_product_meta">
  <id name="asin" column="product_id">
     <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="title" column="title" />
  <property name="avgRating" column="rating" />
  <property name="salesRank" column="sales_rank" />
  <property name="picUrl" column="picture" />
  <set name="reviews" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true">
      <key column="product_id" />
      <one-to-many class="media.definitions.Review" />
   </set>
  <set name="categories" table="dbprak12.view_product_in_category" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
     <key column="product_id" />
     <many-to-many column="category_id" class="media.definitions.Category" />
  </set>
  <joined-subclass name="media.definitions.Book" table="dbprak12.view_book">
     <key column="product_id" />
     <property name="isbn" column="isbn" />
     <property name="publishers" column="publisher" />
     <property name="pubDate" column="publication" />
     <property name="pages" column="pages" />
  </joined-subclass>
  <joined-subclass name="media.definitions.DVD" table="dbprak12.view_dvd">
     <key column="product_id" />
     <property name="format" column="fformat" />
     <property name="regionCode" column="region_code" />
     <property name="runningTime" column="running_time" />
  </joined-subclass>
  <joined-subclass name="media.definitions.Music" table="dbprak12.view_cd">
     <key column="product_id" />
     <property name="labels" column="label" />
     <property name="releaseDate" column="release_date" />
  </joined-subclass>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Review.hbm.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="media.definitions.Review" table="dbprak12.view_customer_evaluates">
 <composite-id>
    <key-property name="accountNumber" column="account_number" />
    <key-many-to-one name="product" class="media.definitions.Product" lazy="false">
       <column name="product_id"></column>
    </key-many-to-one>
 </composite-id>
 <property name="rating" column="points" />
 <property name="content" column="review" />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Edit: My Hibernate configuration file:
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping resource="Product.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Category.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Review.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Person.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Offer.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

db2Module.properties

```
#
# Database module to load
#
middleware.module:media.mediadbimpl.DB2Module

#
# Database properties
#

db.jdbc.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
db.jdbc.driver:com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
db.jdbc.url:jdbc:db2://anyurl.de:50001/datasource
db.user:dbuser
db.password:.dbpass.
```

Comment: Post your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file as well, please?

Comment: Edited my post :) Have a properties file further more, which only sets connection data and dialect (DB2)

Comment: Try declaring the dialect you're using explictly

Comment: I'm already doing that. Declared it in my properties file

Comment: Post said properties file?

Comment: Does the query "from Product p" work?

Comment: Try `select review, p.title from Product p left join p.reviews review`. I'm pretty sure selecting a collection is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This two hql queries work. Only if I choose columns myself to load, the error occurs.
Is there no option to load a collection with a hql query so that I could just use the toString()-Method of a Set?

Comment: @JBNizet make that an answer. JB's query should already have loaded the collection.

Comment: I've read this answer, but the problem is, that I get a (with duplicates filled) list of product titles and to each ONE review. What I wanted was to each product title a Collection of reviews, isn't that possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply select products. You would get waht you want: a collection of products, each having a name and a set of reviews: `select distinct p from Product p left join fetch p.reviews`. Sure, it will load 3 additional columns, but that will probably makes no measurable difference.

Comment: That's right, but as I wrote above is the goal to write functionality to execute any hql query and so I wanted to know if there exists any possibility for my problem. If not, then shit happens :D

Comment: I know is little of topic, but why aren't you using annotations to declare your entities, of course this isn't the problem, but with annotations your code can stay together with the data definitions, making easier to find errors and modify the entities, at least for me, just personal opinion i guess

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this is not a researched answer, so it may be incorrect.

I think your error might be here:

```
<column name="product_id"></column>
```

I think this should be

```
<column name="product_id" />
```

Having body content (even 0 characters) in a tag is different than not having body content.
(comparable to "" and null for string)

the documentation says you can use nested column elements inside the key

```
<key-many-to-one name="product" class="media.definitions.Product" lazy="false">
   <column name="product_id" />
</key-many-to-one>
```

but you don't seem to use it, so you could simply do:

```
<key-many-to-one name="product" class="media.definitions.Product" lazy="false" column="product_id" />
```

the  subtag is usually used for nonstandard columns.

anyways give it a shot

Comment: The <column> element is fine.  That shouldn't be a problem.   The OP doesn't state what version of Hibernate is being used, but I do know that there are older versions that have issues with scalar queries that also retrieve collections which is *exactly* what he's doing here with "SELECT p.reviews, p.title"... p.reviews is a collection and p.title is a scalar.

Comment: @JoshuaDavis might be worth formulating in an answer then :)

Comment: I would if I could understand the goal of the query.  It's kind of an odd thing to do to get a collection and a scalar.   Might as well just get the entities and navigate the object graph to get what you want.   

Although I do agree that your mapping XML is better/cleaner, the mappings in the question should work just the same.